# How much UTF-8 text fits in a MySQL "Text" field?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

According to MySQL, a `text` column holds 65,535 bytes.

So if this a legitimate boundary then will it actually only fit about 32k UTF-8 characters, right? Or is this one of those "fuzzy" boundaries where the guys that wrote the docs can't tell characters from bytes and it will actually allow ~64k UTF-8 characters if set to something like `utf8_general_ci`?

Comment: short answer for your eyes: this much ---> http://pastebin.com/eYUPppw6 (21844 3-byte UTF-8 characters)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

A `text` column can be up to `65,535` bytes.

An `utf-8` character can be up to 3 bytes.

So... your actual limit can be `21,844` characters.

See the manual for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-type-overview.html

> A variable-length string. M represents
>   the maximum column length in
>   characters. The range of M is 0 to
>   65,535. The effective maximum length
>   of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum
>   row size (65,535 bytes, which is
>   shared among all columns) and the
>   character set used. For example, utf8
>   characters can require up to three
>   bytes per character, so a VARCHAR
>   column that uses the utf8 character
>   set can be declared to be a maximum of
>   21,844 characters.

Comment: Where do you get this "up to 3 bytes" figure? UTF-8's encoding of a code point may use anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes.

Comment: @Warren Young, @jcomeau_ictx, @Thanatos: although I completely agree with you. The MySQL manual does not :)

Comment: Wow, so it does. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html clarifies somewhat -- MySQL apparently does not support UTF-8 per se, it supports a subset of it. +1 to you. I like PostgreSQL that much more now.

Comment: This just means MySQL currently has a limit to the range of characters they can accept. When/if they lift the limit and support the full range, assumptions based on the current 3-byte per character value will break. You can count on 4-byte limit forever: the Unicode Consortium has nailed than down for you.

Comment: @Warren Young: that might be true in future cases but expecting how MySQL is going to behave in the future is usually not a good idea. I have been burned by that before ;)

Comment: Most of use will never use characters past the 2byte mark which is why I stuck with 32k rather than naming all possible sizes from mixed UTF-8.

Comment: Bad Answer: `65535/3 === 21845`. UTF-8 Characters can be 4 bytes. `65535/4 === 16383.75`. Round down to `16383`.

Comment: @PHPglue blame the MySQL developers for that, as you can see in the answer it's a quote straight from the manual ;)

Comment: Just cannot believe 7 years after the original post, MySQL is still not solving the problem.....

Comment: @cytsunny the issue is actually far older, I'm not sure about MySQL 3.x but I know this has been the case for MySQL 4.x since the beginning. And that came out in 2002. So... at the very least 15 years

Answer (score 14):

UTF-8 characters can take up to 4 bytes each, not 2 as you are supposing. [UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8), depending on the number of significant bits in the Unicode code point:

- 7 bits and under in the Unicode code point: 1 byte in UTF-8
- 8 to 11 bits: 2 bytes in UTF-8
- 12 to 16 bits: 3 bytes
- 17 to 21 bits: 4 bytes

The [original UTF-8 spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt) allows encoding up to 31-bit Unicode values, taking as many as 6 bytes to encode in UTF-8 form. After UTF-8 became popular, the Unicode Consortium declared that they will never use code points beyond 2<sup>21</sup> - 1. This is now standardized as [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629).

MySQL [currently](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html)  (i.e. version 5.6) only supports the Unicode [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane) characters, for which UTF-8 needs up to 3 bytes per character. That means the current answer to your question is that your `TEXT` field can hold at least 21,844 characters.

Depending on how you look at it, the actual limits are higher or lower than that:

- If you assume, as I do, that the BMP limitation will eventually be lifted in MySQL or one of [its](http://www.drizzle.org/) [forks](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-faq/), you shouldn't count on being able to store more than 16,383 characters in that field if your MySQL client allows arbitrary Unicode text input.
- On the other hand, you may be able to exploit the fact that UTF-8 is a variable width encoding. If you know your text is mostly plain English with just the occasional non-ASCII character, your effective in-practice limit could approach the maximum 64 KB - 1 character limit.

Comment: "can only assume the field can hold up to 16K *characters* of UTF-8 text." ← I'd clarify that...

Answer (score 2):

However, when used as **primary key**, MySQL assumes that each limit of column's size adds **3 bytes** to key.

```
mysql> alter table test2 modify code varchar(333) character set utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table test2 modify code varchar(334) character set utf8;
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

Well, using long string columns as primary key is generally a bed practice, however I've came across that problem when working with database of one commercial (!) product.