# Mysql PDO not inserting serialized php data properly (cuts off at ´ symbol)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am serializing some arrays in php and inserting them into a mysql `TEXT` column.

Some of the data is being badly inserted. An example of the insert statement,

```
$q = $this -> dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO table (files) VALUES(?)");
$q -> execute(array(serialize($files)));
```

The value of `strlen` of the `$files` array is less than that of 65,000 so it doesn't get cut short because of the max insert into a `TEXT` mysql column.

The data of `serialized($files)` before insert,

```
string 'a:4:{s:4:"CD 1";a:20:{s:32:"01 - Can´t Talk To That Girl.mp3";i:4558470;s:22:"02 - No Pla // CONTINUES FOR SOME TIME
```

Value of `$files` grabbed from database,

```
a:4:{s:4:"CD 1";a:20:{s:32:"01 - Can
```

It seems that it cuts short at the character `´`, my understanding of PDO was that it will properly escape all characters for a prepared query?

Just to note my PDO connection is set as `UTF-8`?

How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I can confirm this is due to setting the connection to `UTF-8` any ideas on why PDO would act like this?

Comment: Each UTF-8 character can take up to 3 bytes http://stackoverflow.com/a/4420195/329062

Answer (score 1):

The "´" backquote character in php is a shortcut for system("text between backquotes")

see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

You need to check it is quoted or escaped properly.

Answer (score 0):

Trying not to go to deep down the character encoding rabbit hole; do you have more luck by ensuring your string is UTF-8:

```php
$q = $this -> dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO table (files) VALUES(?)");
$q -> execute( array( utf8_encode( serialize( $files ) ) ) );
```