# Laravel Session Missing after Page Refresh

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have a little problem about sessions in Laravel.

I have made the authentication function which like this:

```
public function postSignin(){
        $attempt = Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')));
        if ($attempt) {
            return Redirect::to('index')->with('message', 'Anda telah login!' . $attempt)
                                        ->with('usersess', Input::get('username'));
        } else if(!$attempt){
                return Redirect::to('auth')
                            ->with('message', 'Kombinasi email/password salah ' . $attempt)
                            ->withInput();
        }
    }
```

let see i have send the **'usersess'** var into session which i consume in my header blade like this: `{{ Session::get('usersess') }}` and place it in the header.

BUT the problem is when i refresh the PAGE, the session is missing! Is there any clue, how to get it back without the session is missing?

i have learn about php and using `<?php session_start() ?>` is the basic function, but how it works in laravel?

thank you!

**UPDATE** my session.php configuration

```
return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'file',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 180,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => array(2, 100),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'invsess',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => false,

 );
```

Comment: can you post your app/config/session.php file please?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange please see the updated section. anyway, FYI, i put the blade into two different page. Which the index is extend the header. I place the session in the header blade, but my routing is going to Index blade. is there the problem?

Comment: You should NOT put session_start() anywhere in your code - Laravel handles all the session wrapping for you.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, RMcLeod has given the solution. thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`->with` flashes data to the session for that page load only. If you want to keep an item in the session use `Session::put('key', 'value')`. So for your example:

```
if($attempt) {
    Session::put('usersess', Input::get('username'));
    return Redirect::to('index')->with('message', 'Anda telah login!' . $attempt);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can use `Session::get('key')` to retrieve a value or `Session::pull('key')` which returns the value and forgets the value. You can also use `Session::forget('key')` to remove an item. `Session::flush()` clears everything from the session.

The session docs can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/session)

Comment: then when i want to remove the session just use Auth::logout(); or just use Session::flush(); ?

Comment: then i will use the flush for logout method :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

This problem is happening for me when I am using

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Instead of it you can use

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

And:

```
//to set a session variable use
$session = new Session();
$session->set('variableName', $requestData['key']);

//to get that session variable
$session = new Session();
$session->get('variableName');
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case this was caused by a dd() that was preventing the request to finish and thus the session to be stored: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927732/laravel-session-facade-unexpected-behaviour)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to contribute to this since I ran into the same issue, but my solution was different than the one up-voted.

After putting items into my session, they were seemingly disappearing on the next page load.

The way I was doing this was via an AJAX call. Whenever I do an AJAX call, I always use an `exit` at the end, to prevent any unnecessary page processing. What I found is that this `exit` was preventing Laravel from proceeding further and actually writing that data into the permanent session.

*Star Fox voice*: Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I was using "dd()" to test and didn't think of this problem.

Comment: I'm not quire sure how much time I waste debugging session issues with `dd()` and `var_dump()+exit` until I found this comment and realized that I'm breaking the session itself. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously not your issue but for anyone else who found this question and the accepted answer does not solve your issue this might:

If you are storing your laravel session in the database there is a limit on how large that session value can be. The Laravel session migration has a field called "payload" that is a text type. If you exceed the limit on that field the entire session gets killed off. This was happening to me as I was dynamically adding json model data to my session.

```
Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

[How much UTF-8 text fits in a MySQL "Text" field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420164/how-much-utf-8-text-fits-in-a-mysql-text-field)

Answer (score 2):

There is one more thing, you always need to remember.
If you have any kind of exit statement in your page, then the session will not be set. This may be after your session setting statements. It can be any code stopping your page. e.g. EXIT function called or dd() function called in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't remove the cookies in your .js. 
That was causing the issue for me:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime()+(-1*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "=;"+" path=/; expires="+now.toUTCString();
document.cookie = "lastpage"+expires;
```