# Laravel 5.1 logout after page refresh

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

in very short, I made fresh install of laravel 5.1 via composer, set everything necessary and it runs without problem. After I followed documentation to create login/register/logout, etc. All works fine, except there is one very important issue.

Everytime I navigate to other page, or refresh current page, I'm instantly logged out. Session are set for 4 hours, storage folder has its rights and followed the documentation of 5.1 and also videos from Laracast. Thing is same with socialite. Login easily, but after refresh Im logged out (session still there, also remember token). Tried this on my mamp, on live server, same result.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958038/laravel-session-missing-after-page-refresh) thread as well, but I believe it works also without manual session set. Or not?

Does anyone else experienced this? Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Database session will sort out your issue.So

1)change session mode "file" to "database".

2) create session table

```
php artisan session:table

composer dump-autoload

php artisan migrate
```

3)Clear config cache and re-set

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: thank you, but this didn't help. I tried the fresh install as well but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the session driver to handle your authentication, you can change the time period for an idle session to expire in the **/app/config/session.php file.**

```
'lifetime' => time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, 
'expire_on_close' => true,
```