# Laravel Session::flash lasts for two requests

Tags: php, laravel, session, view

I'm making an application in Laravel. When using Session::flash to display a message, the Session lasts for two requests (ie the page loads successfully with the message, then when I refresh, it's still there. When I refresh again, it disappears). Here is the code to create the Session and call the view:

```
Session::flash('status', "We are processing refunds for this event. If you are due refunds, check back in 24h.");
view('voucher.index', compact('events', 'orders'));
```

Any views on this are appreciated!

Comment: How are you displaying this flash message in the view?

Comment: '@if (Session::has('status'))
      <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session::get('status') }}</div>
@'

Comment: In a blade.php file

Comment: @frostfat this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958038/laravel-session-missing-after-page-refresh

Answer (score 3):

Use now instead of flash

```
session()->now('message', 'Success! message.');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be returning a view after the action you are doing like that. You should be returning a redirect to a GET route where you will be displaying that view instead.

try this approach:
return redirect()->route(...)->with('success', ....);