# Laravel Session Facade unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.4, php-7.1

In my Laravel 5.4 project I was trying to store a state token in my controller  method like this..

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session ;
 ... 
 public function authorize()
 {
    Session::set('state', $client->getState());

       A lot of code here...

    header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
        exit;
 }
```

I also tried using the helper function

```
  session('state', $client->getState());
```

But no matter what I've tried the session would not be created or persist.

So I switched to using the Symfony component directly..

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
...
public function authorise()
{
   $session = new Session();
   $session->set('state', $client->getState());
   ...
}
```

Doing it this way works perfectly.  Any explanation why the facade is not working?

Comment: what does `$client->getState()` return?

Comment: My first sentence, "store a state token."   It is just random string used to prevent CSRF in an Oauth2 request.  e.g. `LWy7LLRNZc1uXTfe4vXtsXbwGK4Ll7Jd5dEo7QFw`

Comment: Also while troubleshooting I already tested that as a possible cause of course, I just hard coded a key and value like "mykey", "myvalue" rather than using that function.

Comment: check your storage folder permissions

Comment: The permissions are fine, but I am using the sessions database driver any how.  User login session tokens are written just fine to the database or the storage folder depending on which driver I use.

Comment: You could try this syntax `session(['state' => $client->getState()]);`

Comment: @Amr Aly  Thanks I appreciate your help.  As it turns out I was not providing all the info I should have been.  I was implementing a third-party script and oversimplifying it in my question.  I should have mentioned there was a redirect taking place `header('Location: ' . $authUrl);` before the function ended.  I edited the question above to show this now, and also included the explanation below for others reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reference if anyone else has an issue like this, the issue was being caused by a redirect, to an oauth url, before the function finishes, or a view was loaded etc. (i.e. the session gets stored at the end of the Laravel application "lifecycle".) This issue can manifest itself in any number of situations other than just a redirect, including using `dd()` or `die()`etc.

e.g. If your method is basically like this Sessions works fine.

```
public function myAwesomeMethod($params)
{
    Session::put('theKey','theValue');

    return view('theView'); //Session gets stored at this point.
}
```

However if your method looks like something like this you will have an issue.

```
public function myCoolMethod($authUrl)
{
    Session::put('theKey','theValue');

    header('Location: ' . $authUrl); //Session seems to be lost here.
    exit;
}
```

The solution was simple but I missed it because of my unfamiliarity with the Laravel sessions. In the last example simply add the `save()` method to the Sessions class (if using the Facade) like in the following.

```
public function myCoolMethod($authUrl)
{
     Session::put('theKey','theValue');
     Session::save();// Session gets stored immediately

     header('Location: ' . $authUrl); 
     exit;
 }
```