# Session variable on refresh

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4, controller

I have laravel controller like this:

```
public function postSessionTopic() {

    $article_id = Input::get('article_id', 0);
    $comment_id = Input::get('comment_id', 0);

    \Session::set('page_topic_id', $article_id); 
    \Session::set('page_comment_id', $comment_id); 

    \\comment - I have tried \Session::put too, but that doesn't change anything


}
```

I use it, when user click on a article. I print_r out my session variable in this controller and everything looks fine. But after that I refresh my page, and there I read value from session, and sometimes it load old value or doesn't load anything. I can't understand why, because in controller i can see, that correct value is saved!

In my page, i get that value like this:

```
\Session::get('page_topic_id', 0)
```

Comment: check for your session cookie domain, like if your cookie is saved to www.example.org and you access example.loc you'll not access the same session in both

Comment: Domain always is the same

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do something wrong. You should make sure that in both cases you uses exactly same domain (with or without www).

In this controller when you don't have any input you set to session variables `0`. This can also be an issue if you launch this method when you don't have any input.

You could try with adding this basic route:

```
Route::get('/session', function() {

    $page_topic =  Session::get('page_topic_id', 1);

    $page_comment = Session::get('page_comment_id', 1);

    echo $page_topic.' '.$page_comment.'<br />';

    $article_id = $page_topic * 2;
    $comment_id = $page_comment * 3;

    Session::set('page_topic_id', $article_id);
    Session::set('page_comment_id', $comment_id);
});
```

As you see it's working perfectly (but you need to remove session cookie before trying with this path).

You get

```
1 1 
2 3
4 9
8 27
```

and so on. Everything as expected

Comment: How have you tested it? You need to refresh this url manually for example `http://localhost/project/session` and you get values. What values are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was - two ajax at one time. Don't do that, if you store something in session.

Answer (score 0):

The session in Laravel doesn't consider changes permanent unless you generate a response (and that's the result of using symphony as it's base). So make sure your app->run() ends properly and returns a response before refreshing. Your problem is mostly caused by a die() method somewhere along your code or an unexpected exit of PHP instance/worker.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not your issue but if you are storing your laravel session in the database their is a limit on how large that value can be. The Laravel session migration has a field called "payload" that is a text type. If you exceed the limit on that field the entire session gets killed off. This was happening to me as I was dynamically adding json model data to my session.

```
    Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->text('payload');
        $table->integer('last_activity');
    });
```

[How much UTF-8 text fits in a MySQL "Text" field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420164/how-much-utf-8-text-fits-in-a-mysql-text-field)