# Laravel 4.2 Session not Persisting on Browser Refresh

Tags: php, session, laravel-4.2

I have a link on a page that I would like to prevent a user from clicking more than once (or refreshing the route), I need to prevent this with PHP, specifically Laravel 4.2.*

Using Laravel's built in Session handling Facade, at the end of the route being run I add a variable to Session

```
Session::put('preventClick', true);
```

At the start of the method I check if the Session has the item, if false I run the code**

```
if (!Session::has('preventClick')) {
     ... CODE ...
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The check if `Session::has('preventClick')` always evaluates to `false`.

Using PHP native `$_SESSION['preventClick']` works exactly as expected, so why doesn't Laravel's Session class do this? I have tried calling `Session::save()` explicitly after the `Session::put(...)` to make sure, but it still doesn't behave as expected.***

I'd rather keep everything in the Laravel framework, for consistency.

**Full (Simplified) Method**

```
public function placeOrder() {
    if (!Session::has('preventClick') {
        // ... Some code here ... //
        Session::put('preventClick', true);

        return $someValue;
    }
}
```

**NOTE: I understand that the actual prevention of the click cannot be done using PHP alone, but I wish to prevent the code from running.*

***NOTE: Later in the the app I will clear this Session variable when I know that it's no longer needed.*

****NOTE: Laravel Sessions work otherwise, between different page requests / redirects.*

**EDIT**

I found this on another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26165986/1694116

*The session in Laravel doesn't consider changes permanent unless you generate a response (and that's the result of using symphony as it's base). So make sure your app->run() ends properly and returns a response before refreshing. Your problem is mostly caused by a die() method somewhere along your code or an unexpected exit of PHP instance/worker.*

If this is true, this seems to be a problem as I want to stop the code from actually completing a full request...

Comment: Have you verified the script actually gets to the point where you want to set the session variable?

Comment: @CBroe I have indeed, it's a route, and an echo inside the `if(...)` prints out

Comment: Does the session id set in the cookie stay the same, or does that change between requests?

Comment: Just checked, `Session::getId()` reports that the ID is the same between requests.

Comment: What driver are you using to save the sessions?

Comment: @MKJ I am using the `file` driver.