# Actual size of a TEXT field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have read about the size of TEXT field in mysql in this thread:

[How much UTF-8 text fits in a MySQL "Text" field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420164/how-much-utf-8-text-fits-in-a-mysql-text-field)

But still have the following question: if my text is let say a 4 characters long, would it be still saved as TEXT with the max limitation of TEXT memory allocation or only the size of my 4 characters long actual text?

I am asking that because the size won't be the same each time i am inserting a new text

Comment: It will store UP to the limit

Answer (score 0):

Variable length fields like `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` are stored at roughly the size of the element in question. Fixed length fields like `CHAR` are always stored at their *maximum* length, which for UTF-8 encodings is actually 3x the length of the field to reserve enough space for multi-byte characters.

Don't forget that `TEXT` fields tend to be more computationally expensive than `VARCHAR` because they're stored as binary "blobs", not column data. They're useful for when you have large amounts of text, expected to be greater than 1KB typically.